# How do I use Firebase Authentication using multiple view controllers?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am in the process of adding the Create new user Method for `Firebase`. I have already completed the `SignUp` Auth process. However when users are creating a new account. How do I go about this if I have multiple `ViewControllers`?

For example,

The First `SignUpViewController` - User is asked to enter their email address.

When the user clicks next. This is then followed by another `ViewController`.

`SecondViewControlle` - User is asked to enter their name and create a password.

After this, The user is greeted with a Welcome page with their name they submitted. **(Welcome to “App Name” Name)**. Which will then proceed to the home UI after next is clicked.

How do I  implement  The `Auth.auth().CreateUserwith` `func` when I have more than one `ViewController`? Is there a way to save the email and password using two different `ViewControllers`?

Update**

I have added the following code that was suggested below, however the App crashes every time I click next on the enter your " Email" View Controller. I am getting this warning. Does anyone know what I did wrong? The rest of the code seems to be working fine. Here is a screenshot. [image]

Comment: Make a `Singleton Class` and save user's account information in it and process one by one then implement Firebase signup method in last controller with information you have in `Singleton Class`. After successfully logged in show him the Welcome screen. Or you can use `Dictionary` as well.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I will try this!

Comment: Hey! Have you tried below solution?

Comment: I have not yet but I will definitely let you know!

Comment: Actually I got down vote so I thought it was you. I just wanted to know what is wrong in the answer. But anyway .. 

Comment: Could you please accept the answer if it worked for you? Or give any feedback on same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save all information in a `Dictionary` and use it at the time of `SignUp`. In your `AppDelegate` class:

```
/// Instance of AppDelegate
static let shared: AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

/// Dictionary for user information
var userInformation: Dictionary<String, Any> = [:]
```

On Email Screen - Next Button Click

```
/// #1. Validate the email address
/// #2. Save it in Dictionary
AppDelegate.shared.userInformation["email"] = "xyz@gmail.com" or tFEmail.text.lowercased()
```

Then On name and password screen

```
AppDelegate.shared.userInformation["name"] = "xyz" or tFName.text
AppDelegate.shared.userInformation["password"] = "xxxxxxx" or tFPassword.text
```

Now on last screen - Sign Up Button clicked you can use all this information

```
let email = AppDelegate.shared.userInformation["email"]
let name = AppDelegate.shared.userInformation["name"]
let password = AppDelegate.shared.userInformation["password"]
```

Implement the Firebase SignUp method and after successfully logged in show the welcome screen.

Comment: Sorry for the late response mate. I have updated my question with a new warning I am getting after trying out your code. Everything seems to be in working order but the App Delegate. I have added a screenshot above. Did I miss something?

Comment: Hey it should be 'UIApplication.shared.delegate' sorry it's typo mistake from my end. I have updated my answer as well.

Comment: Great! That solved that issue thanks mate. I do have one more issue now and I think this will fix it for good. Do I update my question or ask a completely new one? Sorry I am still new to stackoverflow.

Comment: You should ask a different question instead.